# Board game pawn movement algorithm

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm

I've been working on a board game with a friend of mine. We have managed to get most of it working. The game is called 'jeu de barricade'. Maybe you know it.

The whole board gets created using a Linked List so every field has a 'LinkNorth', 'LinkEast', 'LinkSouth' and 'LinkWest' variable.

Here is the board to give you an idea of how it looks like.

[image: Board Screen]

Now, there is one thing we just can't seem to figure out how to do. Currently, a pawn can be selected, and it can be moved to any field on the board. This of course is not good. 
What we need to do now, is write a method with some sort of algorithm that returns an array or list of the fields the pawn is able to move to. This way, we can check if the selected pawn is actually able to move to the field you clicked on, with the thrown dice number. (a random number from 1 till 6 is generated)
One more thing though. Every 'Field' class has a barricadePawn variable. When this variable contains a barricadePawn object. (barricadePawn != null) the pawn should not be able to move over it. The pawn should be allowed to move onto that field, but not any further. 
(when the player lands exactly on a barricade, he can move it. But we already implemented that, so don't worry about that)

So, in short.
- I want to create a method in our 'Pawn' class, which returns an array or list of all the fields that the pawn should be able to move to. 
- The pawn should be able to move on barricades but NOT over them. 
- The pawn has to move exactly the amount thrown by the dice. So, to get on the finish or on a barricade, you have to throw exactly the right amount.

We have these in our 'Pawn' class:
'currentLocation' contains the field that the selected pawn is currently standing on.

```
private Model.Field startLocation;
private Model.Field currentLocation; 

public List<Model.Field> getPossibleMoves(Model.Field curSpot, int remainingMoves, List<Model.Field> moveHistory)
    {
        List<Model.Field> retMoves = new List<Model.Field>();
        if( remainingMoves == 0 )
        {
            retMoves.Add(curSpot);
            return retMoves;
        }
        else
        {
            moveHistory.Add(curSpot);
            if( curSpot.LinkNorth != null && !moveHistory.Contains(curSpot.LinkNorth) )
            {
                retMoves.AddRange( getPossibleMoves( curSpot.LinkNorth, remainingMoves - 1, moveHistory ));
            }

            if (curSpot.LinkEast != null && !moveHistory.Contains(curSpot.LinkEast))
            {
                retMoves.AddRange( getPossibleMoves( curSpot.LinkEast, remainingMoves - 1, moveHistory ));
            }

            if (curSpot.LinkSouth != null && !moveHistory.Contains(curSpot.LinkSouth))
            {
                retMoves.AddRange( getPossibleMoves( curSpot.LinkSouth, remainingMoves - 1, moveHistory ));
            }

            if (curSpot.LinkWest != null && !moveHistory.Contains(curSpot.LinkWest))
            {
                retMoves.AddRange( getPossibleMoves( curSpot.LinkWest, remainingMoves - 1, moveHistory ));
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is our 'Field' class:

```
public class Field
    {
        protected Field linkNorth, linkEast, linkSouth, linkWest;
        protected Controller.Pawn pawn;
        protected Model.BarricadePawn barricadePawn;
        protected int x, y;

        //Properties:
        public Field LinkNorth
        {
            get { return linkNorth; }
            set { linkNorth = value; }
        }
        public Field LinkEast
        {
            get { return linkEast; }
            set { linkEast = value; }
        }
        public Field LinkSouth
        {
            get { return linkSouth; }
            set { linkSouth = value; }
        }
        public Field LinkWest
        {
            get { return linkWest; }
            set { linkWest = value; }
        }
        public Controller.Pawn Pawn
        {
            get { return pawn; }
            set { pawn = value; }
        }
        public BarricadePawn Barricade
        {
            get { return barricadePawn; }
            set { barricadePawn = value; }
        }
        public int X
        {
            get { return x; }
            set { x = value; }
        }
        public int Y
        {
            get { return y; }
            set { y = value; }
        }
    }
```

If anyone could help us with this, it would be much appreciated. We haven't been able to come up with anything.

Comment: a iterative function should do it. I'd need to to clarify the rules around the die, can you move any numbers of fields up to the die value, or only the number of fields specified by the die, unless you encounter a barricade pawn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating a recursive method.

```
List<Spot> CheckMoves(Spot curSpot, int remainingMoves, List<Spot> moveHistory)
{
    List<Spot> retMoves = new List<Spot>();
    if( remainingMoves == 0 )
    {
        retMoves.Add(curSpot);
        return retMoves;
    }
    else
    {
        moveHistory.Add(curSpot);
        if( !moveHistory.Contains(Spot.North) )
        {

            retMoves.AddRange( CheckMoves( Spot.North, remainingMoves - 1, moveHistory );
        }
        /* Repeat for E, W, S */
    }
}
```

This will return a List (where spot is the class that represents a position on the board) that contains all potential final positions.  Of course you'll need to be a bit more thorough in making sure the Spot.North is a valid spot, but this is a basic idea for you.

The method above won't allow the user to move into the same spot twice in a single move, but doesn't look for barricades or other obstructions.  It also doesn't handle any spots which halt movement or have no possible movement in a particular direction.

It should, however, give you an idea of how it should go.

Comment: I've updated my getPossibleMoves() method with your method. (see main post) I have a good feeling about it, but the compiler is giving me an error that not all possible paths give return value's. Any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: Yes.  Not all the code paths return a value.  Nothing is returned in the 'else' block, is there?  Something should be returned at the end of that else block.  Try returning retMoves in the else block, or at the very end of the method.

Comment: @Snowy007 Also note that there's nothing stopping the same position from being in the return set multiple times, as it currently stands.  You'll probably want to do something to the list to get the distinct objects.

Comment: Modified it to take barricades into account. Working perfectly! Thank you very much!!

Comment: And now you know how recursive methods work, to boot!  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it,

It recusively enumerates each link and adds the `Field`s to a `HashSet` to prevent duplicates. The recursion stops when, the `worp` counts down to `0`, the link is `null` or a `barrier pawn` is located.

```
public IList<Field> GetPossibleMoves(int worp)
{
    var valid = new HashSet<Field>();

    foreach (var f in GetPossibleMoves(current.LinkNorth, worp))
    {
        valid.Add(f);
    }

    foreach (var f in GetPossibleMoves(current.LinkEast, worp))
    {
        valid.Add(f);
    }

    foreach (var f in GetPossibleMoves(current.LinkSouth, worp))
    {
        valid.Add(f);
    }

    foreach (var f in GetPossibleMoves(current.LinkWest, worp))
    {
        valid.Add(f);
    }

    return valid.ToList();
}

private static IEnumerable<Field> GetPossibleMoves(Field current, int worp)
{
    if (current == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    yield return current;

    if (worp == 0 || current.BarricadePawn) // is that a bool?
    {
        yield break;
    } 

    foreach (var f in GetPossibleMoves(current.LinkNorth, nextWorp))
    {
        yield return f;
    }

    foreach (var f in GetPossibleMoves(current.LinkEast, nextWorp))
    {
        yield return f;
    }

    foreach (var f in GetPossibleMoves(current.LinkSouth, nextWorp))
    {
        yield return f;
    }

    foreach (var f in GetPossibleMoves(current.LinkWest, nextWorp))
    {
        yield return f;
    }
}
```

It could be optimised by omitting the calculation of backward moves which would prevent a lot of `Add`s being discarded from the `HashSet`.